# API Telegram returns code 400 on some machines

Tags: telegram

I made application with WebBrowser control, which sends commands to api.telegram.org.
Some computers receive 400 error code with description "chat not found"
I reinstall win7 on my computer and catch a same problem.
By the way, if I navigate address `https://api.telegram.org/bot%token%/sendMessage?chat_id=%chatId%&text=Hello world!` in IE, it will return file SendMessage.json with 200 code.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;                  
string token = tokenvalue;
string chatId = chatidvalue;              
string tgmessage = "Hello world!";                   
string url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatId + "&text=" + tgmessage; 
string urldec = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
try
{
    using (var req = new StreamReader(HttpWebRequest.Create(urldec).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string json = req.ReadToEnd();
        req.Close();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);                                
        }
        else
        {
            // no http status code available
        }
    }
    else
    {
```

1. WebBrowser control's emulation set to 11 version IE.
2. Application is allowed by Windows Firewall.
3. Installed 4.5 Net.Framework and above.
4. All conditions for correct work Telegram bot and current channel.